# How do you send output of argument to another argument

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, output

I want to create a script that needs to take 3 arguments. I want to send the output of the first argument to the second argument and then redirect the final output to a new final. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script that takes three arguments and from within that script you call you three other commands passing each command one of the arguments.

You would use the script like this:

```
./mainScript.sh "arg1" "arg 2" "arg3"
```

Inside the script it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

commandOne "$1"
commandTwo "$2"
commandThree "$3"
```

THis is a very simple example.  Production ready code would validate the number of arguments like this

```
if [ "$@" -ne "3" ]
then 
    echo "must provide three arguments"
    exit
fi
```